Pixel height size of an A4 sheet of paper when printing from chrome
I have a print page that contains different modules that can be different lengths. When I try to print, I would like the next module to be on a separate page if it is greater than 2/3 down the page. In order to do this I use element.getBoundingClientRect(), which I think is in pixels. I need to know the page(A4) height so I can determine where on the individual page the element currently is. Does anyone know these numbers or how I can calculate them?
